# Technology used for charts in Stack*

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph, graphs

I am wondering what technology is used in Stack Exchange to create the graphs like "reputation graph" in the network profile. Is it [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)?

Comment: We also use [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) for many other things, the rep graph many eventually switch over as well.

Comment: @fedorqui: I'm curious about the reason/background of your question ... refer to my profile if you wonder why ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens not very sure about what you mean here :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Seeing as we have a `highcharts.js` sitting in the codebase ;)

Comment: Thanks @Oded! I suspected so but didn't think on checking the codebase :)

Answer (score 1):

The source code is your friend.

Since you already have an idea of what you are looking for, all you need to do is confirm: view source for the page and search for "highcharts". What do you know, there are hits for that term in the source. I think you have your answer.

For most questions of this nature, the fastest way to get an answer is to look at the source. If the answer had not been high charts, you would have needed to find the actual graph item in the DOM and looked for namespace clues or reviewed the list of JS includes. Not the five seconds it took to confirm an answer you already guessed, but still not very long.

Comment: No need to such complicated answer :)

Comment: @fedorqui It's called teaching how to fish rather than just giving you the fish. Next time you can find the answer faster than even asking this question.